# Is there a place to put a breakpoint which will catch all allocations/deallocations of GDI handles?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I am attempting to determine where a GDI leak is coming from in a Windows application and it would help if I could track all the allocations and deallocations of GDI handles.  Is there a couple of functions that I could put a breakpoint on so that I can determine when a GDI handle is being created and when it is being destroyed?

I'm using VC++ and Visual Studio 2013.

I've found [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but I would prefer it if I could get a lower level function that is used for getting/releasing all GDI handles.  I've tried to trace through some assembly without success.

Comment: There are way too many.  Google "gdileaks".

Comment: You could call [GetGuiResources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683192.aspx) before and after calling suspect code, and compare the GDI object counts. Even though this is tedious, you'll get results faster than by digesting piles of debug traces.

Comment: @IInspectable, the code is old and large so although your idea is a good one, it is not helpful in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten about [Detouring](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) as @DavidHefferman suggested (thanks for the suggestion David).  I actually never tried this before, but I did stumble across it last year.  So after a day of trial and error to get the types right, here is an almost complete way of getting this to work.

```
#include <utility>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include "detours.h"

namespace
{
    // To allow for a consistent type for mapping a function pointer
    typedef void(WINAPI *winApiFnPtr)();

    // Storage for funcion info
    struct detourInfo
    {
        LPCSTR fnName;
        LPCSTR typeName;
        winApiFnPtr pOriginalFn;
        winApiFnPtr pTrampolineFn;
        winApiFnPtr pDetourFn;
        detourInfo()
        {
        }

        detourInfo(LPCSTR fnName, LPCSTR typeName, winApiFnPtr pOriginalFn, winApiFnPtr pDetourFn)
            : fnName(fnName)
            , typeName(typeName)
            , pOriginalFn(pOriginalFn)
            , pTrampolineFn(pOriginalFn)
            , pDetourFn(pDetourFn)
        {
        }
    };

    // Stores all the function pointers and other info used by detour.
    std::map<winApiFnPtr, detourInfo> detourFnToInfo;

    // Stores the type of the handle
    std::map<void*, LPCSTR> handleToType;

    // Cast a function pointer to a void *
    template <typename RET, typename...ARGs>
    void* fnToVoidPtr(RET(WINAPI* pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...))
    {
        return (void*)pOriginalFunction;
    }

    // Cast a function double pointer to a void **
    template <typename RET, typename...ARGs>
    void** fnPtrPtrToVoidPtrPtr(RET(WINAPI** pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...))
    {
        return (void**)pOriginalFunction;
    }

    // Sets a value in a map but will assert if value is already there for the
    // given key.
    template <typename K, typename V>
    void set(std::map<K, V>& map, K const& key, V& value)
    {
        auto found = map.find(key);
        ASSERT(found == map.end());
        map[key] = value;
    }

    // Erases a value key pair but will asserts if it doesn't exist.
    template <typename K, typename V>
    void erase(std::map<K, V>& map, K const& key)
    {
        auto found = map.find(key);
        ASSERT(found != map.end());
        map.erase(found);
    }

    UINT fn_ReportIndent = 0;

    // used for type erasure
    void WINAPI fn_CreateReport(void* result, detourInfo const& info, DWORD guiResources)
    {
        TRACE("Created % *sv %s(%p) using function %s. %d handles used.\n"
            , fn_ReportIndent, ""
            , info.typeName
            , result
            , info.fnName
            , GetGuiResources(GetCurrentProcess(), GR_GDIOBJECTS) - guiResources);
        if (handleToType.find((void*)result) != handleToType.end())
        {
            TRACE("% *sWARNING: Didn't find a delete for GDI handle %p of type %s\n"
                , fn_ReportIndent + 10, ""
                , (void*)result
                , info.typeName);
        }
        else
        {
            ++fn_ReportIndent;
        }
        handleToType[(void*)result] = info.typeName;
    }

    template<int DESTROY_PARAM, typename...ARGs>
    static typename std::enable_if<(DESTROY_PARAM == -1)>::type fn_DeleteReportFromCreate(ARGs..., detourInfo const&, BOOL, DWORD)
    {
        // Nothing to do here.
    }

    template<int DESTROY_PARAM, typename...ARGs>
    static typename std::enable_if<(DESTROY_PARAM  > -1) > ::type fn_DeleteReportFromCreate(ARGs...args, detourInfo const& info, BOOL result, DWORD guiResources)
    {
        // The creation is done when an object is deleted.
        // Report the deleted information.
        fn_DeleteReport(std::get<DESTROY_PARAM>(std::make_tuple(args...)), info, result, guiResources);
    }

    // My detour function for a function that creates an object.
    template <int UNIQUE_ID, int DESTROY_PARAM, typename RET, typename...ARGs>
    auto WINAPI fn_Create(ARGs...args) -> RET
    {
        winApiFnPtr pDetourFunction = (winApiFnPtr)fn_Create < UNIQUE_ID, DESTROY_PARAM, RET, ARGs... >;
        typedef RET(WINAPI * fnPtr_t)(ARGs...);
        detourInfo const& info = detourFnToInfo[pDetourFunction];
        DWORD guiResources = GetGuiResources(GetCurrentProcess(), GR_GDIOBJECTS);
        fnPtr_t pOriginalFunction = (fnPtr_t)info.pTrampolineFn;
        RET result = pOriginalFunction(args...);
        // This should work, but has not been tested.
        fn_DeleteReportFromCreate<DESTROY_PARAM, ARGs...>(args..., info, (BOOL)result, guiResources);
        fn_CreateReport((void*)result, info, guiResources);
        return result;
    }

    // used for type erasure
    void fn_EnableCreateDetour(winApiFnPtr pOriginalFunction, winApiFnPtr pDetourFunction, LPCSTR fnName, LPCSTR typeName)
    {
        // if assert occurs within this function, change the UNIQUE_ID to something unique
        set(detourFnToInfo, pDetourFunction, detourInfo(fnName, typeName, (winApiFnPtr)pOriginalFunction, pDetourFunction));

        VERIFY(DetourTransactionBegin() == NO_ERROR);
        VERIFY(DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread()) == NO_ERROR);
        VERIFY(DetourAttach(fnPtrPtrToVoidPtrPtr(&detourFnToInfo[pDetourFunction].pTrampolineFn), fnToVoidPtr(pDetourFunction)) == NO_ERROR);
        VERIFY(DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR);
    }

    // Enables a detour function for a create command.
    template <int UNIQUE_ID, int DESTROY_PARAM = -1, typename RET, typename...ARGs>
    void fn_EnableCreateDetour(RET(WINAPI * pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...), LPCSTR fnName, LPCSTR typeName)
    {
        winApiFnPtr pDetourFunction = (winApiFnPtr)fn_Create < UNIQUE_ID, DESTROY_PARAM, RET, ARGs... >;
        fn_EnableCreateDetour((winApiFnPtr)pOriginalFunction, pDetourFunction, fnName, typeName);
    }

    // used for type erasure
    void fn_DisableCreateDetour(winApiFnPtr pDetourFunction)
    {
        VERIFY(DetourTransactionBegin() == NO_ERROR);
        VERIFY(DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread()) == NO_ERROR);
        VERIFY(DetourDetach(fnPtrPtrToVoidPtrPtr(&detourFnToInfo[pDetourFunction].pTrampolineFn), fnToVoidPtr(pDetourFunction)) == NO_ERROR);
        VERIFY(DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR);

        erase(detourFnToInfo, pDetourFunction);
    }

    // Disables a detour function for a create command.
    template <int UNIQUE_ID, typename RET, typename...ARGs>
    void fn_DisableCreateDetour(RET(WINAPI * pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...))
    {
        winApiFnPtr pDetourFunction = (winApiFnPtr)fn_Create < UNIQUE_ID, RET, ARGs... >;
        fn_DisableCreateDetour(pDetourFunction);
    }

    // used for type erasure
    void WINAPI fn_DeleteReport(void * handle, detourInfo const& info, BOOL result, DWORD guiResources)
    {
        auto found = handleToType.find(handle);
        if (found != handleToType.end())
        {
            TRACE("Deleted % *s^ %s(%p) using function %s. Success = %d. %d handles released.\n"
                , --fn_ReportIndent, ""
                , found->second
                , handle
                , info.fnName
                , result
                , guiResources - GetGuiResources(GetCurrentProcess(), GR_GDIOBJECTS));
            handleToType.erase(found);
        }
        else
        {
            TRACE("Deleted % *s| UNKNOWN(%p) using function %s. Success = %d. %d handles released.\n"
                , fn_ReportIndent, ""
                , handle
                , info.fnName
                , result
                , guiResources - GetGuiResources(GetCurrentProcess(), GR_GDIOBJECTS));
        }
    }

    // My detour function for a function that destroys an object.
    template <int UNIQUE_ID, int DESTROY_PARAM, typename...ARGs>
    auto WINAPI fn_Delete(ARGs... args) -> BOOL
    {
        typedef BOOL(WINAPI * fnPtr_t)(ARGs...);
        winApiFnPtr pDetourFunction = (winApiFnPtr)fn_Delete < UNIQUE_ID, DESTROY_PARAM, ARGs... >;
        detourInfo const& info = detourFnToInfo[pDetourFunction];
        DWORD guiResources = GetGuiResources(GetCurrentProcess(), GR_GDIOBJECTS);
        fnPtr_t pOriginalFunction = (fnPtr_t)info.pTrampolineFn;
        BOOL result = pOriginalFunction(args...);
        void* handle = (void*)std::get<DESTROY_PARAM>(std::make_tuple(args...));
        fn_DeleteReport(handle, info, result, guiResources);
        return result;
    }

    // used for type erasure
    void fn_EnableDestroyDetour(winApiFnPtr pOriginalFunction, winApiFnPtr pDetourFunction, LPCSTR fnName)
    {
        auto found = detourFnToInfo.find(pDetourFunction);
        if (found == detourFnToInfo.end())
        {
            set(detourFnToInfo, pDetourFunction, detourInfo(fnName, "", (winApiFnPtr)pOriginalFunction, pDetourFunction));

            VERIFY(DetourTransactionBegin() == NO_ERROR);
            VERIFY(DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread()) == NO_ERROR);
            VERIFY(DetourAttach(fnPtrPtrToVoidPtrPtr(&detourFnToInfo[pDetourFunction].pTrampolineFn), fnToVoidPtr(pDetourFunction)) == NO_ERROR);
            VERIFY(DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR);
        }
        else
        {
            ASSERT(found->second.pOriginalFn == (winApiFnPtr)pOriginalFunction);
            ASSERT(found->second.fnName == fnName);
        }
    }

    // Enables a detour function for a destroy command.
    template <int UNIQUE_ID, int DESTROY_PARAM, typename...ARGs>
    void fn_EnableDestroyDetour(BOOL(WINAPI * pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...), LPCSTR fnName)
    {
        winApiFnPtr pDetourFunction = (winApiFnPtr)fn_Delete < UNIQUE_ID, DESTROY_PARAM, ARGs... >;
        fn_EnableDestroyDetour((winApiFnPtr)pOriginalFunction, pDetourFunction, fnName);
    }

    // used for type erasure
    void fn_DisableDestroyDetour(winApiFnPtr pDetourFunction)
    {
        auto found = detourFnToInfo.find(pDetourFunction);
        if (found != detourFnToInfo.end())
        {
            VERIFY(DetourTransactionBegin() == NO_ERROR);
            VERIFY(DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread()) == NO_ERROR);
            VERIFY(DetourDetach(fnPtrPtrToVoidPtrPtr(&detourFnToInfo[pDetourFunction].pTrampolineFn), fnToVoidPtr(pDetourFunction)) == NO_ERROR);
            VERIFY(DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR);

            erase(detourFnToInfo, pDetourFunction);
        }
    }

    // Disables a detour function for a destroy command.
    template <int UNIQUE_ID, int DESTROY_PARAM, typename...ARGs>
    void fn_DisableDestroyDetour(BOOL(WINAPI * pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...))
    {
        winApiFnPtr pDetourFunction = (winApiFnPtr)fn_Delete < UNIQUE_ID, DESTROY_PARAM, ARGs... >;
        fn_DisableDestroyDetour(pDetourFunction);
    }
}

void captureAllGdiCalls()
{
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateBitmap, "CreateBitmap", "HBITMAP");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateBitmapIndirect, "CreateBitmapIndirect", "HBITMAP");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateCompatibleBitmap, "CreateCompatibleBitmap", "HBITMAP");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateDIBitmap, "CreateDIBitmap", "HBITMAP");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateDIBSection, "CreateDIBSection", "HBITMAP");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<1>(CreateDiscardableBitmap, "CreateDiscardableBitmap", "HBITMAP");
    fn_EnableDestroyDetour<0, 0>(DeleteObject, "DeleteObject");

    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateIcon, "CreateIcon", "HICON");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CopyIcon, "CopyIcon", "HICON");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateIconFromResource, "CreateIconFromResource", "HICON");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateIconFromResourceEx, "CreateIconFromResourceEx", "HICON");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateIconIndirect, "CreateIconIndirect", "HICON");
    fn_EnableDestroyDetour<0, 0>(DestroyIcon, "DestroyIcon");

    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateBrushIndirect, "CreateBrushIndirect", "HBRUSH");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateDIBPatternBrush, "CreateDIBPatternBrush", "HBRUSH");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateDIBPatternBrushPt, "CreateDIBPatternBrushPt", "HBRUSH");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateHatchBrush, "CreateHatchBrush", "HBRUSH");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreatePatternBrush, "CreatePatternBrush", "HBRUSH");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateSolidBrush, "CreateSolidBrush", "HBRUSH");
    fn_EnableDestroyDetour<0, 0>(DeleteObject, "DeleteObject");

    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateDCA, "CreateDCA", "HDC");
    fn_EnableDestroyDetour<0, 0>(DeleteDC, "DeleteDC");
    fn_EnableDestroyDetour<0, 1>(ReleaseDC, "ReleaseDC");

    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateEnhMetaFileA, "CreateEnhMetaFileA", "HDC");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0, 0>(CloseEnhMetaFile, "CloseEnhMetaFile", "HENHMETAFILE"); // closing the HDC metafile creates an HENHMETAFILE
    fn_EnableDestroyDetour<0, 0>(DeleteEnhMetaFile, "DeleteEnhMetaFile"); // deleting the HENHMETAFILE deletes it all

    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateFontA, "CreateFontA", "HFONT");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateFontIndirectA, "CreateFontIndirectA", "HFONT");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateFontIndirectExA, "CreateFontIndirectExA", "HFONT");
    fn_EnableDestroyDetour<0, 0>(DeleteObject, "DeleteObject");

    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateCompatibleDC, "CreateCompatibleDC", "HDC");
    fn_EnableDestroyDetour<0, 0>(DeleteDC, "DeleteDC");

    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateMetaFileA, "CreateMetaFileA", "HDC");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0, 0>(CloseMetaFile, "CloseMetaFile", "HMETAFILE"); // closing the HDC metafile creates an HMETAFILE
    fn_EnableDestroyDetour<0, 0>(DeleteMetaFile, "DeleteMetaFile"); // deleting the HMETAFILE deletes it all

    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreatePalette, "CreatePalette", "HPALETTE");
    fn_EnableDestroyDetour<0, 0>(DeleteObject, "DeleteObject");

    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreatePen, "CreatePen", "HPEN");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreatePenIndirect, "CreatePenIndirect", "HPEN");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(ExtCreatePen, "ExtCreatePen", "HPEN");
    fn_EnableDestroyDetour<0, 0>(DeleteObject, "DeleteObject");

    WINGDIAPI int     WINAPI CombineRgn(_In_opt_ HRGN hrgnDst, _In_opt_ HRGN hrgnSrc1, _In_opt_ HRGN hrgnSrc2, _In_ int iMode);
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateEllipticRgn, "CreateEllipticRgn", "HRGN");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreateEllipticRgnIndirect, "CreateEllipticRgnIndirect", "HRGN");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<0>(CreatePolygonRgn, "CreatePolygonRgn", "HRGN");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<1>(CreateRectRgn, "CreateRectRgn", "HRGN");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<2>(CreateRectRgnIndirect, "CreateRectRgnIndirect", "HRGN");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<3>(CreateRoundRectRgn, "CreateRoundRectRgn", "HRGN");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<4>(ExtCreateRegion, "ExtCreateRegion", "HRGN");
    fn_EnableCreateDetour<5>(PathToRegion, "PathToRegion", "HRGN");
    fn_EnableDestroyDetour<0, 0>(DeleteObject, "DeleteObject");
}

void stopCaptureOfAllGdiCalls()
{
    for (auto& info : detourFnToInfo)
    {
        VERIFY(DetourTransactionBegin() == NO_ERROR);
        VERIFY(DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread()) == NO_ERROR);
        VERIFY(DetourDetach(fnPtrPtrToVoidPtrPtr(&info.second.pTrampolineFn), fnToVoidPtr(info.second.pDetourFn)) == NO_ERROR);
        VERIFY(DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR);
    }
    detourFnToInfo.clear();
}

void showAllTrackedHandles()
{
    TRACE("Active GDI handles (%d):\n", handleToType.size());
    UINT counter = 0;
    for (auto handleTypeTuple : handleToType)
    {
        TRACE("  % 7u: %p %s\n", ++counter, handleTypeTuple.first, handleTypeTuple.second);
    }
    TRACE("End of active GDI handles\n");
}

void clearAllTrackedHandles()
{
    handleToType.clear();
}
```

I say almost complete because:

1. It would seem that not all of the functions as described in the [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) actually use up GDI handles, but this could be getting stock objects that are preallocated.
2. As well, all of the functions specified are not the only ones to allocate GDI handles as some show up as UNKNOWN.

Anyway, this should put me on my way to finding the leak.  I just call `captureAllGdiCalls()` before an operation that should allocate the GDI objects, and when I think that all of the GDI elements that have been allocated should have been deallocated I call `stopCaptureOfAllGdiCalls()`.  Listing what handles remain and their type is done by calling `showAllTrackedHandles()` and clearing them is done by calling `clearAllTrackedHandles()`.  Then it is just a matter of trying to get a stack trace to see where the handles that should have been destroyed are not and figure out why.

For those interested, here is a sample of the traced output:

```
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(174) : atlTraceGeneral - Created v HBITMAP(73052029) using function CreateDIBitmap. 1 handles used.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(174) : atlTraceGeneral - Created  v HBITMAP(C5050792) using function CreateDIBitmap. 1 handles used.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted   | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(174) : atlTraceGeneral - Created   v HDC(93011E42) using function CreateCompatibleDC. 1 handles used.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(174) : atlTraceGeneral - Created    v HBITMAP(CE051F02) using function CreateBitmap. 1 handles used.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(269) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted    ^ HBITMAP(C5050792) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(269) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted   ^ HDC(93011E42) using function DeleteDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(174) : atlTraceGeneral - Created   v HBITMAP(170564FF) using function CreateDIBitmap. 1 handles used.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(174) : atlTraceGeneral - Created    v HBITMAP(27051EDB) using function CreateDIBitmap. 1 handles used.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted     | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(174) : atlTraceGeneral - Created     v HDC(C3012732) using function CreateCompatibleDC. 1 handles used.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(174) : atlTraceGeneral - Created      v HBITMAP(2D051DFA) using function CreateBitmap. 1 handles used.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(269) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted      ^ HBITMAP(27051EDB) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(269) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted     ^ HDC(C3012732) using function DeleteDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted     | UNKNOWN(C7050792) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted     | UNKNOWN(ED051E2A) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted     | UNKNOWN(018503F1) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 0 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted     | UNKNOWN(211064D6) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 2 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted     | UNKNOWN(FF1041E0) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 0 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted     | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted     | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted     | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted     | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted     | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted     | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted     | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted     | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(174) : atlTraceGeneral - Created     v HBRUSH(221064D6) using function CreatePatternBrush. 2 handles used.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted      | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(174) : atlTraceGeneral - Created      v HBRUSH(001041E0) using function CreateSolidBrush. 0 handles used.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(DA014EBF) using function ReleaseDC. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(174) : atlTraceGeneral - Created       v HRGN(EA041E0B) using function CreateRectRgn. 1 handles used.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(269) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       ^ HRGN(EA041E0B) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 0 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(030A1E2A) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(040A1E2A) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(050A1E2A) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(060A1E2A) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(070A1E2A) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(080A1E2A) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(090A1E2A) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(0A0A1E2A) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(280) : atlTraceGeneral - Deleted       | UNKNOWN(0B0A1E2A) using function DeleteObject. Success = 1. 1 handles released.
...
```

It indents one space for every creation and removes an indentation space when a tracked handle is destroyed.

Here's a sample of the tracked handles that haven't been deleted:

```
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(435) : atlTraceGeneral - Active GDI handles (225):
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -         1: 000563C0 HBITMAP
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -         2: 001041E0 HBRUSH
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -         3: 0205072F HBITMAP
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -         4: 0513085F HICON
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -         5: 060A1AF1 HFONT
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -         6: 070A0161 HICON
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -         7: 07102AED HBRUSH
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -         8: 07790699 HICON
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -         9: 08055812 HBITMAP
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -        10: 09050DF2 HBITMAP
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -        11: 0A051467 HBITMAP
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -        12: 0F050DAF HBITMAP
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -        13: 0F05470B HBITMAP
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -        14: 100522F7 HBITMAP
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -        15: 10054212 HBITMAP
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -        16: 13055D51 HBITMAP
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -        17: 1405084D HICON
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -        18: 140530EF HBITMAP
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -        19: 16103C8B HBRUSH
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -        20: 170564FF HBITMAP
...
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -       220: F5301F67 HPEN
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -       221: F60507C0 HBITMAP
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -       222: F7052C7E HBITMAP
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -       223: F81066CA HBRUSH
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -       224: FF0127BE HDC
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(439) : atlTraceGeneral -       225: FF054CD8 HBITMAP
d:\projects\test\test\test.cpp(441) : atlTraceGeneral - End of active GDI handles
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a direct, easy way to do this.

One way you could do it is to backup all your windows header files, and then comment out the GDI functions you're using in the windows header files. Then, re-declare the function yourself and implement it like so:

```
#define CreateSolidBrush(a) _mCreateSolidBrush(__FILE__, __LINE__, a)

WINGDIAPI HBRUSH WINAPI _mCreateSolidBrush(const char *_file, unsigned long _line, COLORREF c)
{
    typedef HBRUSH (*csb)(COLORREF);
    csb _CreateSolidBrush = (csb) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("gdi32.dll"), "CreateSolidBrush");
    HBRUSH retVal = _CreateSolidBrush(c);

    // do reference counting for number of open handles per file and line
    return retVal;
}
```

If you don't want to do that, you could try debugging through process of elimination. Basically, comment out all GDI handle allocations/releases, except for one. Test if it's leaking memory and if not, uncomment another GDI handle allocation/release.

I hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: That's not tractable. Detouring might be.

Comment: This is essentially the same as detouring, you're redirecting the function to one that you write. I also updated my answer to show how it could be managed.

Comment: `_mCreateSolidBrush` and `_CreateSolidBrush` are reserved symbols, and should only be used by the C++ implementation. More importantly, though, your function pointer signature doesn't contain a calling convention. This will eventually break, and turn into a hard to find bug.

Comment: It's easy enough to rename the symbols. Also, the calling convention can easily be specified: typedef __stdcall HBRUSH (*csb)(COLORREF). My answer still stands - this is a viable way to track GDI handle reference counts.

Comment: Not if they are in a external library.  But thanks for the idea.